# Owncloud - How create a folder using API?

Tags: owncloud

How create a folder in ownCloud using API ?

I'm searching about it , but found nothing.

I'm using ownCloud version 8.2.1

Regards,

Comment: Found it - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In their official docs you can find it [here](http://api.owncloud.org/classes/OCP.Files.Folder.html#newFolder)**

> *Create a new folder*
>
> `newFolder(string $path) : \OCP\Files\Folder`
>
> *Parameters*
>
> `$path - a string (the relative path of the folder)`